# Java ZonedDateTime.toInstant() behavior

Tags: java, python, django, java-time, pytz

I'm running the below expressions on **December 7th, 2018**.

I'm seeing a discrepancy whereby this:

```
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).minusDays(30)
```

returns (correctly):

```
2018-11-07T22:44:11.242576-05:00[America/New_York]
```

whereas conversion to an instant:

```
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).minusDays(30).toInstant()
```

seems to mess up the result **by adding an extra day to it**:

```
2018-11-08T03:58:01.724728Z
```

I need an instant conversion to use its result in the following code as Date:

```
... = Date.from(t.toInstant())
```

An equivalent Python code (Django) works correctly:

```
datetime.datetime.now('America/New_York')+datetime.timedelta(days=-30)
```

evaluating to: `datetime: 2018-11-07 20:13:55.063888-05:00`

What's causing the discrepancy?

What should I use so that Java conversion to Date resulted in the **November 7th** being returned, just like in Python's case?   Basically, I'm looking to an equivalent translation of that Python code into Java, or in pseudocode:

```
`datetime.X = datetime.now(deployment_zone) - (N_days)`,

where `deployment_zone` is configurable (i.e. `America/New_York`)

`N_days` is configurable (i.e. 30)
```

---

*Update for @Basil Bourque:*

When I formulated the original question, I (per SO rules) tried to simplify it to a digestible form which probably destroyed most of the necessary context making it vague.  Let me try again.

As I explained in the comments, I'm converting the existing Python code (which is more actively maintained and which client wants to keep intact) to existing Java code (legacy that has not been properly maintained and strayed away from the Python's logic some time back).  Both code bases need to be functionally on par with each other.  Java needs to do what Python is already doing.

**Python code** is as follows (I'm lumping all into one place for succinctness, in reality it's distributed across a couple of files):

```
analytics.time_zone=America/New_York
TIME_ZONE = props.getProperty('analytics.time_zone', 'UTC')
TZ = pytz.timezone(TIME_ZONE)

    def days_back(num_days=0):
            adjusted_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(TZ)+datetime.timedelta(days=-num_days) 
            return DateRangeUtil.get_start_of_day(adjusted_datetime)

class DateRangeUtil():

    @staticmethod
    def get_start_of_day(date):
        return date.astimezone(TZ).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

which basically takes the configured time zone, in which it obtains the current instant, subtracts a specified number of days from it, converts it to the beginning of that date and thus receives the lower bound of the range to use while querying the DB, something like Start time: `datetime: 2018-11-07 20:13:55.063888-05:00`

When I started on the **Java side**, it had:

```
    public final static DateRange parse(String dateRange) {
                //.....
                        int days = ...
                        return new DateRange(toBeginningOfDay(daysBack(days)), toEndOfDay(daysBack(0)));

    private final static Date daysBack(int days) {
                return toDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(days));
            }

private final static Date toBeginningOfDay(Date d)
        {
            Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(d);
            c.set(HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
            c.set(MINUTE,0);
            c.set(SECOND,0);
            c.set(MILLISECOND, 0);
            return c.getTime();
        }

        private final static Date toDate(LocalDateTime t) {
            return Date.from(t.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        }
```

That code didn't work and introduced the *discrepancy* which I describe in my original question.  I started experimenting and introduced ZonedDateTime into the picture.  While investigating, I found that it's the call to .toInstant() that seems to be a culprit and wanted to understand what's behind it in more depth.

[In his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53679471/283837), @ernest_k suggested a solution which seemed to have worked, but I still didn't quite understood which is clear from questions in the comments to his response.

The changes I made based on @ernest_k response are as follows:

```
private final static Date daysBack(int days) {

            return toDate(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).minusDays(days).toLocalDateTime());

private final static Date toDate(LocalDateTime t) {
            return Date.from(t.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        }
```

This seems to produce the desired outcome:  However conversion from local to zoned and then back again seemed too much, so I experimented a bit more and found that simply the LocalDateTime does the trick as well:

```
private final static Date toDate(LocalDateTime t) {
            return Date.from(t.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        }

private final static Date daysBack(int days) {
            return toDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(days));
        }
```

I can see that `LocalDate` (and perhaps `LocalDateTime`) has a convenient `atStartOfDay()` which seems to be a fitting candidate for elimination of `Date`s out of the picture while replacing the legacy `toBeginningOfDay(Date d)` method above.  Not sure it's doing the same thing - I haven't yet experimented with that idea, so the suggestions are most welcome.

So, with all of the tribulations above, my question started around `toInstant()` behavior, and when it's passed a zone id, whether it converts **TO** an instant in that zone, or **FROM** it, or *what*?

I guess for the situation I'm describing we only care that the lower time bound in the DB query is formed by comparing some *consistent* marker of current time (its upper bound) to what it was in the same place (time zone?) in the past N days, so comparing it with *UTC* should server the purpose.

Does that then make passing the zone in unnecessary?

Now, that a solution seems to have been found, the question revolves around the soundness of the approach described above and the solution that's been stumbled upon - is it the most optimal one, best practices around Java timing libs, etc.  The code needs to work for any time zone in which the code bases will end up being deployed, that's why the zone is passed in via configuration.

Also, I wonder if things change when/if the DB itself is deployed off-premise from the rest of the codebase and is configured to persist data in some other time zone.  But that might be another question.

Comment: Do you just need November 7th, or do you also need the same time of day as now?

Comment: The logic is to subtract certain (configurable) amount of days from the current day.     The zone id ('America/New_York') is also parameterized and configured, I simply hardcode those values here for simplicity.  So, if run on Dec-8th, I'm expecting Nov-8th to be returned, on Dec 7th - Nov 7th will be returned, and so forth.

Comment: For example, if run on `Fri, Dec-7, 8:14pm`


Python would return: `datetime: 2018-11-07 20:13:55.063888-05:00` but Java wouldn't.  I'm expecting similar result on the Java side as well.

Comment: For those of us who don’t know (enough) Python, maybe if you explain what you need the date for, we can better suggest.

Comment: I've updated the question with pseudocode of what I'm after.  This is a refactoring of the existing codebase to bring it on par with Python, so I'm trying to do it with minimal amount of changes, hence removing their (heavy) usage of `Date` is undesirable (at least at this point).

Comment: It sounds to me like if you stick to `ZonedDateTime` and don’t use `Instant` and `Date`, you have what you want? Why the need to convert? And if you do need to, what are the precise requirements of the converted value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184911/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-simeon-leyzerzon).

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

`ZonedDateTime.toInstant()` adjusts a moment from a time zone to UTC. You end up with the same moment, different wall-clock time, and **possibly a different date** for the same simultaneous point on the timeline. What you are seeing is not a problem, **not a discrepancy**.

Your problem is not with subtracting 30 days. The real problems:

- Not understanding that time zone affects the date
- Conflating dates with days

Furthermore, your Question is vague. Saying “30 days ago” can mean at least three different things:

- 30 * 24 hours
- A range from 22:44 thirty calendar days ago in New York time zone to 22:44 now in New York time
- The entire day today as seen in New York and the entire days going back 30 days on the calendar as seen in New York.

All three possibilities are covered below, with example code, labeled with `➥`.

## ⑦  ↔  ⑧

On the 7th of December, shortly before midnight (22:44), Alice in her New York apartment decides to call her friend Bob in Reykjavík, Iceland. Bob can't believe his phone is ringing, and looking over at the clock on his bedside table sees the time is almost 4 AM (03:44). And Bob's fancy digital clock shows the date as the 8th of December, not the 7th. Same simultaneous moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time, **different date**.

The people of Iceland use UTC as their time zone, year-round. New York is five hours behind UTC in December 2018, and so five hours behind Iceland. In New York it is “yesterday” the 7th while in Iceland it is “tomorrow” the 8th. Different dates, same moment.

So forget about subtracting the thirty days. Any time you take a moment in New York that is close to midnight, and then adjust to UTC, you will be moving the date forward.

**No discrepancy, no extra day added.** For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. With a range in time zones of about 26-27 hours, it is always “tomorrow” and “yesterday” somewhere.

[Another Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53679471/642706) suggests involving [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) into this problem. That is ill-advised. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. That means a `LocalDateTime` *cannot* represent a moment. A `LocalDateTime` represents *potential* moments along the range of 26-27 hours mentioned above. Makes no sense to involve that class here.

Instead, use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) for a moment viewed with an offset-from-UTC, versus [`ZonedDateTime][2]` which uses a time zone.

What is the difference between an offset and zone? An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds, nothing more, nothing less. A zone, in contrast, is *much* more. A zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of particular region. So a time zone is always preferable to a mere offset, as it brings more information. If you want UTC specifically, you need only an offset, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Adjust from a time zone to UTC.
```

The `zdt` and `odt` seen here both represent the same moment, the same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time, like Alice and Bob example above.

## Days != Dates

If you want to query for a range of thirty days ago, you must define what you mean by “days”.

### Days

➥ Do you mean 30 chunks of 24-hour long spans of time? If so, work with [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). This class represents a moment in UTC, always in UTC.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
Instant instantNow = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from time zone to UTC. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
Instant instantThirtyDaysAgo = instantNow.minus( 30 , ChronoUnit.DAYS ) ; // Subtract ( 30 * 24 hours ) without regard for dates.
```

You *may* be able to exchange an `Instant` with your database via your JDBC driver. But `Instant` is optional, while support for `OffsetDateTime` is required by [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) and later. If that is the case, let's re-write that code.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
OffsetDateTime odtNow = zdt.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Adjust from time zone to UTC. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
OffsetDateTime odtThirtyDaysAgo = odtNow.minusDays( 30 ) ;
```

Your SQL might be something like the following.

Note what we are using the Half-Open approach to defining a span-of-time, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This is generally best practice, as it avoid the problem of finding the infinitely divisible last moment, and it provides for neatly abutting spans without gaps. So we do *not* use the SQL command `BETWEEN`, being fully-closed (inclusive on both ends).

```sql
SELECT * FROM event_ WHERE when_ >= ? AND when_ < ? ;
```

Set values for the placeholders in your prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , odtThirtyDaysAgo ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , odtNow ) ;
```

### Dates

➥ If by “30 days ago” you meant 30 boxes on the calendar hanging on the wall in a New York office, that is a very different problem.

#### Same time-of-day

And if so, do you mean from the current moment and moving back 30 days to the same time-of-day?

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtThirtyDaysAgo = zdtNow.minusDays( 30 ) ; // `ZonedDateTime` will try to keep the same time-of-day but will adjust if that time on that date in that zone is not valid.
```

With the code seen above, the `ZonedDateTime` class will try to use the same time-of-day on the earlier date. But that time may not be valid on that date in that zone, because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) cutover. In such an anomaly, the `ZonedDateTime` class adjusts to a valid time. Be sure to study the JavaDoc to understand the algorithm and to see if it suits your business rules.

Pass to your prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , zdtThirtyDaysAgo ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , zdtNow ) ;
```

#### Entire day

➥ Or by “30 days ago” do you mean dates, and by dates you mean all-day-long?

If so, we need to focus on the date-only value, by using `LocalDate` class, without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 ) ;
LocalDate thirtyDaysAgo = tomorrow.minusDays( 30 ) ;
```

Now we need to go from the date to a specific moment by assigning a time-of-day and a time zone. We want the time to be the first moment of the day. Do not assume that means 00:00. Because of anomalies such as DST, the day may start at another time such as 01:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day on that date in that zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = thirtyDaysAgo.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = tomorrow.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Pass to your prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , zdtStart ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , zdtStop ) ;
```

Comment: Perhaps it's unclear: I'm subtracting the 30 (or N) days (from now) in order to form a date range to use in a DB query (in case no explicit start and end date to that query were provided), not because I'm just trying to change the date to a different value.  Such is the application logic on the Python side of things from which I'm converting.

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon Your confusion has *nothing* to do with subtracting days. The problem is not understanding time zone handling, and conflating dates with days.

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon Your question is vague. Saying “30 days ago” can mean at least three different things: (a) 30 * 24 hours, (b) a range from 22:44 thirty calendar days ago in New York time zone to 22:44 now in New York time, (c) The entire day today as seen in New York and the entire days going back 30 days on the calendar as seen in New York. I covered all three in my Answer with example code. Take your pick.

Comment: That moment is used to form a lower bound in the DB query, so it tries to count the provided number of days back to get the same moment in the corresponding past day and then starts from the beginning of that found day.  I put more context into my original query, hopefully the context is clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

That "extra day" is not really an extra day. `2018-11-07T22:44:11` in New York is equivalent to `2018-11-08T03:58:01` in UTC (it's the same point in time). The difference is just `5` hours, not a day (and when I google this, I see New York is `GMT-5`).

`ZonedDateTime#toInstant` returns an `Instant` instance representing the same point in time (in UTC):

> Converts this date-time to an Instant.
>   This returns an Instant representing the same point on the time-line as this date-time. The calculation combines the local date-time and offset.

If you want to **not** use the offset when converting to instant, then you should perhaps use `LocalDateTime`:

```
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
      .toLocalDateTime()
      .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

This tells it to convert as though it were already UTC time (but a warning is appropriate here: ***this changes the date/time value***)

Comment: That suggestion seems to work, but I still don't understand why.  What's the need to convert to `LocalDateTime`.  What's the difference between that and the `ZonedDateTime` with a specified zone id?

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon `ZonedDateTime.toInstant()` takes the offset (of the relevant time zone) into account, but `LocalDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)` doesn't (`LocalDateTime` doesn't have timezone or offset information, and specifying `UTC` forces it to treat the time as though it were already UTC time, so that it won't add/remove any offset value).

But you need to be sure that this is what you want, as it effectively changes the "point in time" value.

Comment: Would these 2 expressions be equivalent: `LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(days)` vs. `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).minusDays(days).toLocalDateTime()`?  What do you mean by saying: `it effectively changes the "point in time" value`?

Comment: I'm sure they will, but only if they run on a computer in New York. (so that `LocalDateTime.now()` picks up the desired values)

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid the need for an old-fashioned `Date` if you can. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, gives you all the functionality you need.

Sometimes we do need a `Date` for a legacy API that we cannot change or don’t want to upgrade just now. Java *is* giving you what I think you want. Demonstration:

```
    ZonedDateTime nov7 = ZonedDateTime.of(2018, 11, 7, 22, 44, 0, 0,
            ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
    Instant inst = nov7.toInstant();
    System.out.println("As Instant: " + inst);
    Date oldFashionedDate = Date.from(inst);
    System.out.println("As Date: " + oldFashionedDate);
```

Output from this was:

> ```
> As Instant: 2018-11-08T03:44:00Z
> As Date: Wed Nov 07 22:44:00 EST 2018
> ```

Admitted, to get this output I had to change my JVM’s default time zone to America/New_York first.

`Date` and `Instant` are roughly equivalent but print differently. Meaning their `toString` methods behave differently, which may be confusing. Each is a point in time, none of them is a date (despite the name of one of them). It is never the same date in all time zones.

`Date.toString` picks up your JVM’s time zone setting and uses it for generating the string it returns. `Instant.toString` on the other hand always uses UTC for this purpose. This is why the same point in time is printed with different date and time. Fortunately they both also print a bit of time zone information so the difference is at least visible. `Date` prints `EST`, which, albeit ambiguous, in this case means Eastern Standard Time. `Instant` prints `Z` for offset zero from UTC or “Zulu time”.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm looking for a functionally equivalent translation of the Python expression above.  On the Java side, as soon as I tack `toInstance()` to the (`run date` minus `days offset`) expression, I get back to the bumped up time value again (from the 7th to the 8th in my case), which was undesirable.  I do have some code that then takes the Nov 7th date time and converts it to the beginning of that day.  It's excluded for clarity.  I wasn't sure what was causing that behavior and weather it had anything to do with time zones or not. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I am sorry that I don’t know the Django/Python type. What I do know is that a Java `Date` cannot give you a date and time of day — only a point in time not tied to any time zone or UTC offset.